# how to check if value contain white space - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing simple module for prestashop.in my admin controller i have input text called `username`.i want user to enter his user name without space.

**what i tried**

i have added below code in to Validate.php and tried to access it from Module class.but its not working.

**Validate.php**

```
public static function checkWhiteSpace($var){
  return preg_match('/\s/',$var);
}
```

**Model class**

```
class User extends ObjectModel
{

  public $id_user;
  public $username;

  public static $definition = array(
      'table' => 'Users',
      'primary' => 'id_user',
      'multilang' => false,
      'fields' => array(
          'username' => array(
              'type' => self::TYPE_STRING,
              'required' => true,
              'validate' => 'checkWhiteSpace',
          ),
    ),
);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to invert your result from Validate. Because when your field is invalid it shows true and opposite when valid. So try this

```
public static function checkWhiteSpace($var){
    return !preg_match('/\s/',$var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work within your Model class, you don't need to change Validate.php.